# How can Cooper pairs be stable?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

In the BCS theory, a Cooper pair is formed by two electrons of nearly opposite momentum $(k \sim -k')$. What I don't understand is how can this structure remain stable in the metal:

1. Assume that the two electrons do not have any interaction with other electrons and ions. Then they will move far away from each other, and eventually lose contact.
2. If they do interact with other electrons or ions (the mean free path of electrons is $10\sim 30 \mathrm{nm}$ in metals), then upon scattering their movements will change randomly, so that $k$ is no longer close to $-k'$.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Crystal momentum is not momentum. If a scattering event does not have enough energy to overcome the pairing energy, the pair is not broken.

Comment: Let's say electron A collides with something and totally changes its momentum from k1 to k2. Initially electron B's momentum is close to -k1. What is the mechanism for electron B to follow electron A to change its momentum from -k1 to -k2? How can scattering (electron energy ~EF) have a lower energy than the pairing energy (much less than EF)?

Comment: The coupling between electrons in a Cooper pair is an effective coupling (mediated by phonons) rather than a permanent coupling. So, if electron A scatters from momentum k1 to k2, it will couple (via phonons) to electrons with momentum -k2.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism for the formation of Cooper pairs and guarantor of their stability is the electron-phonon interaction (at least this is the one we understand: the BCS mechanism).  An electron distorts the ion lattice and creates a region of net positive charge, which attracts another electron.  As metals (Fermi liquids) are unstable to attractive interactions, the system has the possibility of changing dramatically -- in this case, from a metal to a superconductor -- and scattering techniques from Fermi liquid theory should be used with caution.  Nevertheless, using BCS theory one assumes the electron-phonon interaction is small, so is treated as a perturbation.

To see this in a more rigorous manner, consider the following Hamiltonian:

$$
H = H_{el} + H_{ph} + H_{el-ph}, 
$$

where the three pieces are the electron Hamiltonian, the phonon Hamiltonian, and the electron-phonon Hamiltonian respectively.  The electron Hamiltonian reads

$$
H_{el} = \sum_{k, \alpha\beta,\sigma} t_{\alpha \beta,\sigma} (k) c^\dagger_{k,\alpha,\sigma} c_{k, \beta,\sigma},$$
which is a familiar tight-binding Hamiltonian that governs the band structure of the metal.  The $c_{k, \alpha, \sigma}$ operators are electrons of crystal momentum $k$, orbital index $\alpha$, and spin $\sigma$.  The phonon Hamiltonian reads
$$
H_{ph} = \sum_{q,a,b,\lambda,\lambda'} {\hbar} W_{a,b,\lambda,\lambda'}(q) b^\dagger_{q,a,\lambda} b_{q,b,\lambda'},
$$ where the operator $b_{q,a,\lambda}$ is a phonon of momentum $q$, ion index $a$, and polarization $\lambda$.

These are the simple parts -- the crux of the physics lies in the electron phonon interaction:

$$
H_{el-ph} = \sum_{\alpha,a,k,q,\lambda,\sigma} g_{\lambda,a,\alpha}(k,q) c^\dagger_{k-q,\alpha,\sigma} c_{k,\alpha,\sigma}(b^\dagger_{q,a,\lambda} + b_{-q,a,\lambda}).
$$

Physically, the electron of momentum $k$ scatters off the ion lattice, creating a phonon of momentum $q$ and changing the momentum of the electron to $k - q$.  The same phonon, at second order in perturbation theory, will scatter off another electron of momentum $k'$ and change its momentum to $k' + q$.  For a Cooper pair, $k' = -k$, so this process does not change the fact that the scattered momenta are opposite: $k - q = -(-k + q)$.

TLDR: the phonon that mediates the attractive interaction ensures the momentum exchange between electrons is not random.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive picture: One electron with momentum k will attract the ions and make ions surrounding it get closer along its way. This makes the potential higher along the path of this electron and thus an electron with opposite momentum will travel along this path so that a cooper pair forms.